# Action Type C# can return a type?

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I am looking at a code and i see it say

```
public Action<MainViewModel, MainViewModel> SetView { get; }
```

Does this indicate that the action `SetView` is receiving something?  I thought action types were always void?

Also, what what is the `(ViewModel.SetView)` portion mean? is that type casting to a `SetView`?

```
SetView = new Action<MainViewModel,MainViewModel>(ViewModel.SetView)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, `Action<T>` does not return anything. `Func<T>` does.

Comment: `Does this indicate that the Action SetView is receiving something?`  It indicates that SetView is returning an `Action<MainViewModel, MainViewModel>` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Action` type can only pass parameters.  If you want to return a value, then you can use `Func<>`.

In your example, `SetView` is a property that takes an `Action<MainViewModel,MainViewModel>`, which means that the property should be set to a method that accepts 2 MainViewModels as parameters, so something like:

```
void MyMethod(MainViewModel model1, MainViewModel model2)
{ ... }
```

Except that yours is just a getter, so I assume it was set in a constructor.

To answer your further questiom,  this is the [prototype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-2?view=net-5.0) for Action<T1,T2>:

```
public delegate void Action<in T1,in T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
```

SetView = new Action<MainViewModel,MainViewModel>(ViewModel.SetView);

This is calling the set method on property SetView, with a method (ViewModel.SetView) that takes 2 MainViewModel parameters.

Is it possible that you have a property called SetView in one class and a function called SetView in the view model class?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, could you explain this portion ```SetView = new Action<MainViewModel,MainViewModel>(ViewModel.SetView)```, i would of expected it to have been ```SetView = new Action<MainViewModel,MainViewModel> FunctionName(Parameter)``` but theres just a parameter ViewModel.SetView, what about the function?